# How to reduce time of the parsing and inserting into database when there is bulky data on web in android?

Tags: android, database, parsing

i am working on bible project in android and having more 30000 text rows on web.I want to parse that data using dom parsing and insert into the database.The problem here is that the it takes more than 15 minutes to get response,then parse it and then fill into database.And after filling into the database.I show that data using query methods.So the user is blocked for 15 minutes which is very bad impression.How can i reduce the parsing and inserting into database time.

Comment: There is no answer to your question, as this question will get closed soon.. 1) Don't deal with 30000 text rows together, get data's on demand 2) Parsing logic should be in background thread 3)only use main thread for UI operation.. If your app makes user wait for 15 minutes, then it is a sure no-use..

Comment: thanks @Krishnabhadra  if i get data on demand then there are many buttons in bible and on each click on button user face the parsing and inserting.But if i have done whole parsing in one then the user is free and enjoy the app.So how can i reduce the total time.any help is appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to parse and store into the database so better way is to load in some range like 0-50-100-150 or 0-100-200.

So You can achieve this by using ListView with load Button. You can make it like it will load automatically while scrolling to position say 50 or 100 what ever its up to you.

Or else you while scrolling the a footer will be added to the ListView at the end i.e say 50 0r 100.

For reference go through the following link.

https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

Hope this will help you to achieve your requirement.

Many Thanks.

Comment: ji if i change the approach of 30,000 in one time ,then i do this in partition of 10,000 per time but the problem is as it is the time is not reduced as i want.Suggest me the approach to reduce parsing and inserting time.